# Python ModuleNotFoundError despite the modules being installed

Tags: python, libraries

While importing:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyttsx3'
```

Comment: Might be possible that now you are working in a new environment then before and they are not installed here(new env). So just check the environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls.run `pip list` in the same virtual env and check if your modules are present in the list.

Also, pls.run in the python terminal the same import first.

Comment: is it possible that import isn't looking in the right directory or something??cz speechrecognition and other packages that I installed all have the same error...and if so...pls help how to correct it...i see there are many others with the same problem without any solution.

Comment: Pls. check ```which python``` command and ensure that it is same for where you have installed and where you are importing.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Python 3 and your pip is installed and functional (you might need to use sudo or run command as admin, depending on your OS):

```
sudo pip uninstall speechrecognition
sudo pip install speechrecognition --no-cache-dir
```

And then:

```
sudo pip uninstall pyttsx3 
sudo pip install pyttsx3 --no-cache-dir
```

No cache dir option will make sure that you download dependencies from scratch in case your previous download in cache had any problems.
It could also be that your are using a VENV or your Environment variables are messed up.
Make sure which Python and Pip are you using:

```
python --version
pip -V
```