# from utils import show_test_cases, test_case_checker, perform_computation

Tags: python, importerror

I am trying to  do this

```
from utils import show_test_cases, test_case_checker, perform_computation
```

using jupyter notebook, but I am facing ImportError

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in 
> ----> 1 from utils import show_test_cases, test_case_checker, perform_computation
> ImportError: cannot import name 'show_test_cases' from 'utils' (C:\Users\samee\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\utils_*init*_.py)

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Is this useful to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64301324/python-modulenotfounderror-despite-the-modules-being-installed/64301365#64301365 ?